# Java best practice or are there any design patterns to keep data filed which hasn't a direct relationship with that class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, attributes

I just want to pass the value with the object but that value is not completely related to that object. Let's say there is an object call Request Data

```
public class RequestData
{
  private int requestId;
  private String status;
 .......
}
```

I want to pass is this request need to save only or print only or both save and print likewise there are several actions. When I pass this request data to another class to validate this requestData, I want to identify is it coming from save or print or save and print call. For that, basically, I can add an attribute to that RequestData class. But according to my learning in OOP, We should keep  attributes related directly to that objects as attribute of that object.

Then what is the best practice or are there any design patterns to keep data filed which hasn't a direct relationship with that class.

Comment: You can try defining a _requestType_ attribute - and this identifies if its a print or save or whatever. Define this attribute an an _enum_. This way if another type like _delete_ is needed you can add a new value to the enum. If the attributes and behavior are more varying to each type, one can consider using a base abstract class and extend it to make specific sub-classes.

Comment: Here is [Factory_method_pattern on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: You can have the validation routine(s) within the `ReaquestData` class itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right! Putting an unrelated attribute into you class would make difficult to reuse the class in another environment which does not require that unrelated attribute.

A typical solution is to create another class that makes use of the old class:

```
class SecondRequestData {
    private RequestData origin;
    private bool isSave;
    private bool isPrint;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted this technique is called _composition_.

Answer (score 1):

Define a request type attribute - and this identifies if its a *print* or *save*. Define this attribute as an *enum*. This way if another type like "query" or "update" is needed you can add a new value to the enum class. It is also documentation of the code and the functionality.

Here is what the code can look like:

```
enum RequestType { SAVE, PRINT }

class RequestData {
    private int requestId;
    private String status;
    private RequestType requestType;
    .......
    // Get/set methods for request type
    public RequestType getRequestType()
        return this.requestType;
    }
}

class UtilityClass {
    static boolean validateRequestData(RequestData req) {
        switch (req.getRequestType()) {
            case SAVE: // do save related validation
            case PRINT: // do print related validation
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal request type");
        }
        ...
    }

    // private boolean ... detailed validate methods called from switch-case.
}

public class RunMyApp {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ...
        // Invoke the request data validation
        RequestData rd1 = new RequestData();
        rd1.setRequestType(RequestType.PRINT);
        if (UtilityClass.validateRequestData(rd1) {
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your response

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, add all properties related to the request to the RequestData class (the request type seems to me is a property of the request). 
Regarding validation, if the validity of the request depends on the place it is validated (where the request is handled) then keep it outside, if the validity of a request is based only on the data inside the RequestData object then, put the validate method inside this class

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you Request data class should have a [state](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) *requestAction* which should state what action it should perform. In your case it could be save, print, both, etc.

In future, if more actions are introduced you need not to modify your code ([Open close principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle))
You could enumerate values which requestAction could take.

```
public class RequestData
{
  private int requestId;
  private String status;
  private String requestAction ;
 .......
}
```